# perl, parsing emails immediately

Tags: perl

i would like to setup a system where I can start parsing emails using perl (in unix i guess) from some account and a cron job would trigger this. I was wondering if anyone has setup something similar to this.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Is there a specific problem you're trying to overcome?

Comment: If you want to do it *immediately* (as your subject suggests), use procmail.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common enough task. If you're checking an account for new messages, and processing them, you may want to split the task up like this:

1. Use a CPAN module like [Net::IMAP::Client](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-IMAP-Client/) to access the inbox, or pipe messages to procmail (or a procmail alternative like [Mail::Audit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-Audit/))
2. Parse the message, either using your folder reading module's default interface, or using a tool like [Email::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Email-Simple/) or [Email::MIME](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Email-MIME/) to read the message.
3. Don't forget to mark that you've seen that message, e.g. by marking it read, deleting it, or moving it to another folder